# Ruby interface for sqlite3 fails , need help !!! :(

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I was trying to install sqlite3 interface for ruby in my Ubuntu 10.10.
But i got the following error any suggestions ?

```
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:  
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.  

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb  
extconf.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)  
    from extconf.rb:3  

my rails and related versions are as follows:-  
saran@ubuntu:~$ ruby -v  
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]  
saran@ubuntu:~$ gem -v  
1.3.7  
saran@ubuntu:~$ rails -v  
Rails 3.0.1  
saran@ubuntu:~$ sqlite3 --version  
3.7.2  
saran@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev ruby-dev
```

Then try installing the gem.